# search phrase string using jpa queries

Tags: spring-data

I have a search  with JPA query using Spring Data like this :

My interface repository :

```
public interface AnnonceDao extends   JpaRepository<Annonce, Integer> {
    Page<Annonce> findByTitreContaining(String titre,Pageable page);
}
```

when I look for something like **Hello Friend** I get all entities that have Hello Friend concatened , I want something to get **Friend Hello** too or any entity that contains **Hello** or **Friend**. what I can use as Query, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public interface AnnonceDao extends   JpaRepository<Annonce, Integer> {
    Page<Annonce> findByTitreContainingAndTitreContaining(
        String part1, 
        String part2,
        Pageable page
    );
}
```

If the number of terms you want to pass is unknown at compile time, as you explain in the comment you can use [Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

This leaves the task of creating the specification to the client of the repository. If you don't like that you can provide a custom method and dynamically create a query inside. Again you have the choice of multiple technologies:

- SQL
- JQL
- QueryDsl

[QueryDsl looks actually really nice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26563841/66686) and readable as you can see in the linke example.

Comment: thanks Jens for your answer , actually the number of words is  known , it s kind of  search so I don t have number of words in my string.